# If classes match add class to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to add a class to a div which has the same class as another div on the page, can anyone help me with this?

I have a category div

```
<div id="featured" class="camera">Category</div>
```

And an accordion with headers and content area.

```
<h2 class="header in-active cameras"></h2>
<div class"content in-active cameras"></div>   

<h2 class="header in-active sound"></h2>
<div class"content in-active sound"></div>
```

What I am trying to do is if the header & content have the same class as the category div then add a class called active. I need to do this dynamically as the category class's are created with php.

Anyone have a jQuery method of doing this?

Comment: Duplicate `id` attributes are invalid.

Comment: __IDs must be unique__ Change your strategy

Comment: An element can have more than one class attribute so that probably suits your purpose better than IDs

Comment: So if I swap the id's with classes?

Answer (score 0):

You can only have an ID called once in a webpage, otherwise it is not valid. Use multiple classes instead.

```
<h2 class="header cameras"></h2>
<div class="content cameras"></div>
```